# takeLast seems to kill observable stream

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm trying to setup an observable stream where I compare the most recent set value to the last one, and I'd like to filter based on some changes between the two. I setup a BehaviorSubject in a service (Angular 2, if that matters) and created  function to return it:

```
getFilters() {
    return this.filtersSubject.asObservable();
}
```

Then in the component using it, I'm trying this:

```
this.eventFilterService.getFilters()
    .takeLast(2)
    .subscribe((data) => console.log(data));
```

But I get no console logs. If I remove the `takeLast`, I see my data returning. From the docs, my assumption would be as is, it would just fire twice. My goal was to feed the `takeLast` into a reduce then a filter.

Am I using takeLast wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`takeLast(x)` will wait for completion of the Observable before it can emit the last `x` emissions. Since you use a subject you need to invoke `complete()` for it to work.

But you really want to calculate a difference between two emission. To do so use the `.buffer()` operator

```
Rx.Observable.from([2,3,5,8])
     .bufferCount(2,1)
     .map(buff =>  buff[1] - buff[0])
     .subscribe(delta => console.log(delta))
```

Comment: [`buffer`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-buffer) takes an observable. I think you'd want to use [`bufferCount(2, 1)`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-bufferCount).

Comment: you are correct; should not write SO answers on my phone while commuting ;-)

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into both functions. I assume take also waits for a buffer to complete? This is why I hate the Rx docs... the examples suck :/ I realize now what the docs mean by completion.

Comment: Sorry, looking at the bufferCount docs, I don't think that's quite right either; it seems to cluster events, so according to the docs, I'd get 1,2 then 3,4. I want 1,2, then 2,3, then 3,4 so I can compare each event to the previous.

Comment: bufferCount has a second argument the 'skip' which says how many elements to advance before the next buffer. So `bufferCount(2,1)` will create `[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]` whereas bufferCount(2,3) would create `[1,2],[4,5],...` etc

Comment: Of course, I lament how I dislike the docs, then go to the docs and dismiss your answer. I'm really sorry. If I had just tested the code first instead of complaining, I would have seen you were right off the bat. Thank you so much.

Comment: So looks like it works as you said, but I'm getting really strange results, and I don't understand what's going on. I think I'll have to put up another SO question...